# Подключение функции к боту

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, telegram

Я пытаюсь сделать в своем боте функцию поиска айди по юзернейму в тг. Код я уже написал и он работает:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
def get_user(username):
    API_ID = айди
    API_HASH = "хеш"
    client = TelegramClient('назв приложения', API_ID, API_HASH)
    client.connect()
    user = client.get_peer_id(username)
    return user

ids = get_user("@айди")
print(ids)
```

Работает это через мое приложение, и токен моего бота. Однако при подключении к боту при абсолютно аналогичном коде получаю ошибку

```
File "C:\Users\Alex\PycharmProjects\osint\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\telegrambaseclient.py", line 473, in loop
  return asyncio.get_event_loop()
File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 642, in get_event_loop
  raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'WorkerThread2'.
```

Сам код внутри бота выглядит так(использую библиотеку telebot):

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def text_message(message2):
    if (message2.text)[0] == "@":
        bot.send_message(message2.chat.id, f"Начинаем поиск по тг {message2}")
        from telethon.sync import TelegramClient

        def get_user(username):
            API_ID = айди
            API_HASH = "хеш"
            client = TelegramClient('название приложения', API_ID, API_HASH)
            client.connect()
            user = client.get_peer_id(username)
            return user

        ids = get_user(message2.text)
        print(ids)
```

Comment: Тут видимо будет конкурс....

Comment: А зачем вы в функцию text_message вложили get_user? Может стоит вынести в отдельный файл?

Comment: Нашёл в интернете похожие ситуации: [вот](https://qna.habr.com/q/1000131) и [вот](https://qna.habr.com/q/828223).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я подозреваю, что Вы просто не в том потоке. Смотрите [тут](https://pypi.org/project/pyTelegramBotAPI/) написано что аннотация `@bot.message_handler` позволяет функции обрабатывать сообщения. Но в ошибке Вам пишут

> There is no current event loop in thread 'WorkerThread2'

Что явно намекает на то, что Вы просто работаете не в том потоке, в котором есть цикл обработки сообщений. Ведь что бы Ваше сообщение пришло в функцию, помеченную аннотацией, в потоке должен быть цикл обработки сообщений.